# How do I get this raster and this shapefile on the same projection?

Tags: r, raster, projection, r-raster

I have a shapefile of 10 CA counties projected in NAD83(Hard)/CA Albers. I have a raster (a netCDF file of temperature) for the entire US projected in WGS84/WGS84. I want to use the shapefile to clip the raster. I know that I need to get them on the same datum/projection first. But I've tried re-projecting the raster using raster::projectRaster(). That failed (as in the data disappeared). So then I tried re-projecting the shapefile instead using sp::spTransform(). This also failed (as in the data don't overlap). I've searched through stackoverflow but didn't see anything that seemed to help. I'm not getting an error, but `projectRaster` is not working and re-projecting the shapefile using `spTransform` doesn't produce the desired outcome. I feel like there is something specific going on here, like the transformation from WGS84 to NAD83 or loading the raster in using `raster()` is the problem ... but then again, it could easily be something stupid that I'm missing! =)

my shapefile and raster are here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l3b2syzcioeqmyy/AAA5CstBZty4ofOcVFkAumNYa?dl=0

here is my code:

```
library(raster) #for creating rasters from .bil files
library(rgdal) #for reading .bil files and .gdb files
library(ncdf4) #for working with ncdf files
library(sp) #for working with spatial data files

load(my_counties.RData)
myraster <- raster(myraster.nc)
my.crs <- CRS("+init=EPSG:3311") #NAD83(HARN) / California Albers (HARN is high resolution)

newraster <- projectRaster(myraster, res = 6000, crs = my.crs) #raster resolution is 1/16th of a degree

#There is data in the raster.
plot(myraster)

#but none in newraster
plot(newraster)

#Now try re-projecting the shapefile
my.crs2 <- crs(myraster)
newshapefile <- spTransform(my_counties, my.crs2)

#but the data don't overlap
plot(newshapefile); plot(myraster, add = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

load("my_counties.RData")
b <- brick("myraster.nc")
```

Now look at `b`

```
b
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 490, 960, 470400, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 0.0625, 0.0625  (x, y)
#extent     : 234, 294, 23.375, 54  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : myraster.nc 
#names      : X2005.01.01, X2005.01.02, X2005.01.03, X2005.01.04, X2005.01.05, X2005.01.06, X2005.01.07, X2005.01.08, X2005.01.09, X2005.01.10, X2005.01.11, X2005.01.12, X2005.01.13, X2005.01.14, X2005.01.15, ... 
#Date       : 2005-01-01, 2005-12-31 (min, max)
#varname    : tasmax
```

The horizontal extent is between 234 and 294 degrees. That points to a system with longitudes that start in Greenwich at 0 and continues to 360 (again in Greenwich). Climatologist do that. To go to the more conventional -180 to 180 degrees system:

```
r <- shift(b, -360)
```

(if your data had a global extent, you would use `raster::rotate` instead)

Now, transform the counties to lonlat and show that they overlap.

```
counties <- spTransform(my_counties, crs(r))
plot(r, 1)
lines(counties)
```

It is generally best to transform vector data, not raster data if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for that clear and concise explanation! This also explains why I was getting an error when trying raster::rotate ("doesn't look like an appropriate object for this function"). After shifting the extent I was also able to get spTransform to work on the shapefile!